# React Router and Context not working together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass data from my sites.

I decided to use React Context for this and implement a high layer Context (called DataContext). However the dashboard I am using also implements React router.

How can I make both work together?

Let DataStore be the ContextProvider:

```
  import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
  import DataStore from "./context/DataStore";
  const hist = createBrowserHistory();

  ReactDOM.render(
    <DataStore>
      <Router history={hist}>
        <Switch>
          {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
            return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
          })}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Datastore>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

Above code does not work as of now and I don't know why.

TypeError: render is not a function

DataStore.jsx:

```
  import React from "react";

  export const DataContext = React.createContext();

  class DataStore extends React.Component {
    state = {
      data: {}
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={this.state.data}>
          {this.props.children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  export default DataStore;
  ~
```

I access the Provider like this:

```
import {DataContext} from "../../context/DataStore";

class Accessor extends Component {

  render() {
    <DataContext.Consumer>
      <Item>
    </DataContext.Consumer>
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the current state is, Is there an error in the console?

Comment: you haven't imported ReactDOM in your code

Comment: I did but decided to not show it here

Comment: Where does this error point to. Also if you could show your DataStore ccomponent it might help in figuring out your issue

Comment: Ok I added the other components, the error points to Reacts internal components. React is trying to update the Consumers, hence my assumption that it might have to do with the updating of consumers and how react wires the app with the routers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Used [react-redux](https://redux.js.org/) instead, which worked in the same scenario and configuration.

Comment: it was really helpful. Thanks